# Unity c# use dropdown value in addition code rather than dropdown string name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drop-down-menu, type-conversion

I am currenly learning C# and unity to work on my own game, currently I am attempting to use the dropdown UI to choose between crops to grow in a farm building holding the list in a data management script.

I want to bring the variable over and use in an addition script so that the number of crops will increase based on a delay and generation number, when i try to bring the variable over it add the name of the item rather than using it to add the numbers together, I attempted to use Convert.ToInt32 and a temp variable to go around this but it does not read the numbers and add them.

Main script

```
[SerializeField]
private dataManager dataScript;

[SerializeField]
private Text Grain, Veg;

[SerializeField]
private float delay, delayBase;

[SerializeField]
private int stringToInt1, stringToInt2;

[SerializeField]
private string Items, itemGeneration;

public Dropdown farmDropdown;

Coroutine farming;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
  GameObject dataObj = GameObject.Find("Base");
  dataScript = dataObj.GetComponent<dataManager>();

  farming = StartCoroutine(farmGrowth());

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
  Grain.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = ("Grain: " + dataScript.grain.ToString());
  Veg.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = ("Veg: " + dataScript.veg.ToString());

  delay = delayBase;
}

public void dropdown_IndexChanged(int index)
{
  Items = dataScript.ItemChoices[index];
  itemGeneration = dataScript.itemGenerationChoices[index];
}

private IEnumerator farmGrowth() {
  while (true) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    farmGeneration();
  }
}

  private void farmGeneration(){
    stringToInt1 = Convert.ToInt32(Items);
    stringToInt2 = Convert.ToInt32(itemGeneration);
    stringToInt1 += stringToInt2;
    //Items += itemGeneration;
  }
```

Data script

```
public int grain, veg;
public int grainGeneration, vegGeneration;
public List<string> ItemChoices = new List<string>() { "grain", "veg"};
public List<string> itemGenerationChoices = new List<string>() { "grainGeneration", "vegGeneration"};
```

This is the code at the moment, it's all just me learning and figuring out what I can do and how to do a simple version of it, the bottom is supposed to read what is chosen in the dropdown, get what crop is to grow, then add the generation amount onto the total crops held, for example:
grain += grainGeneration

Comment: Can you remove everything which is not related to the dropdown problem, please? Make it a [MRE] (focus on minimal)

Comment: What I am trying to do is get the value from the pulled in listed items to use in dataScript.X and dataScript.Y where X and Y are the values that Items and itemGeneration hold, i.e. grain and grainGeneration, so ideally something like dataScript.(Items) += dataScript.(itemGeneration) but in a way that will actually work

Comment: Well, that's because you are converting a string that doesn't have any number in it. `ToInt32` expects strings like `"0"` or `"1"`. I'm not sure about what you're trying to do; it might be useful if your example showed what you wanted to do with stringToInt1. If you want to add two ints together before appending them to a string, you can do it like so `"A string" + (int1 + int2);`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood the issue, the following code simply lets the program know what you want form the dropdown.

```
public Dropdown crops;
public string selected;

void Start()
{
   crops.onValueChanged.AddListener(
            delegate
            {
                DropdownValueChanged();
            });
}

void DropdownValueChanged()
{
   switch(crops)
   {
     case 0:
        selected = "bananas";
        break;
   }
}
```

PS: I can't comment but as mentioned on the comments you should make your question more clear with just the essential information. if you have various things to do just enumerate them so its easier for others to follow and help.